# Results from mysqli_fetch_assoc() with nul query result

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to query a MySql database table in php to determine whether an entry exists.  If it does exist, I want to know its ID so I can use it as a Foreign Key in another table. If it does not exist, I want to add the new entry and query its autoincremented ID for use as the foreign key.

First, I execute a mysqli_query command and assign the handle to $query.

If the entry does not exist, the command

```
$result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)['id'];
```

returns nul.  However, when I test this, using:

```
if ($result = "")
{
//commands
}
```

the if statement doesn't execute, as if the test is returning false.  What am I doing wrong here, or is there a better way to accomplish the result I am looking for?

Comment: If your query is returning false it has failed. Check the value of mysqli_error for the reason. I'll bet you have a syntax error in your query.

Comment: Check what exactly `mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)` returns using `var_dump()`

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're running PHP 5.5, you cannot use an array returned from a function/method call and immediately dereference it. Try using the standard pre-5.5 syntax:

```
$result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
if ($result['id']) { 
   ...
}
```

instead. As well, note that your sample if() command is wrong. A single `=` does assignment, **NOT** an equality test. You probably wanted

```
 if ($result == "")
             ^^---note, 2 ='s
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

use '==' instead of '=' in your if query. And the comparison should be to FALSE, not to ''. To be absolutely sure, you can use the strict comparison '==='

```
if($result === FALSE)
```

I do not agree to the part of the above answer where $result['id'] is being referenced immediately after the  mysql_fetch_assoc call; that code does NOT check that the mysql_fetch_assoc indeed returned an array, and it will produce a PHP notice.

I would write it as

```
$result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
if ($result === FALSE) { 
   // no result
}else{
    $id = $result['id'];
}
```